# Allocating the correct size of struct variable with sub-structs

Tags: c++, struct, casting, size

So I am trying to allocate the correct size for a variable. Then copy another variable to this new one and later access the new variable's data.

**Structs:**

```
struct Validations {

    int validationId;
    int count;  // total queries
    char queries[];
};

struct Query {

    struct Column {
      enum Op : int { Equal, NotEqual };
      int column;
      int value;
      Op op;
    };

    int relationId;
    int columnCount;    // total columns
    Column columns[];
};
```

**Code:**

```
// function that creates the new val
void function1(Validations* val){
    int size = sizeof(Validations) + val->count;
    Validations *new_val = (Validations*)malloc(size);
    memcpy(new_val, val, size);

    // I store this val in a global list
}

void function2(){
    // I pop the val here

    // I am casting here in order to get the values that i want
    const char* reader = popped_val->queries;

    for (...){
        // casting again
        const Query* q = (Query*)reader;

        // operations....
        // SIGSEGV here after reader is incremented and q is casted again

        // done with operations, go to next
        reader += sizeof(Query)+(sizeof(Query::Column)*q->columnCount);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the new_val size that I am allocating in the first function is probably not the right one because I get a segmentation fault after the second cast of the function2 after trying to access the data.

What I tried:

1) `size = 1000;` Tried that for testing and it worked so the problem is surely the size.

2) `size = sizeof(Validations) + val->count * sizeof(Query) * sizeof(Query::Column) * q->columnCount;`. This one looks like the correct one to me but it does not work.

Comment: Your question is tagged C++ but you're using a feature of C99 and C11 (flexible array members) that is not a part of standard C++.  If you're getting it anywhere close to compiling, then you are probably using G++ or perhaps Clang++ to do the compilation.  You have an FAM in `struct Validations`; is that really characters?  If you're using C++, you should really be using vectors or something similar in place of the flexible array, members.  And you probably shouldn't be using `malloc()` at all — that is C coding and not C++ coding.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The question was originally tagged C. I retagged it C++ because the posted code is clearly not C.

Comment: @trentcl: Hmmm…yes, the `enum` notation is C++11 if not C++14.  But then the use of `[]` for flexible array members is not strictly valid in C++ (any version).  The code is a messy hybrid.  It isn't clear to me that the `char queries[];` is what's wanted (I suspect the intent was to allow `Query queries[];` but that leads to loops and prohibitions).  If it is C++, the whole approach using `malloc()` is anti-paradigmatic — not the way it should be done (`std::vector<…>` is more likely to be appropriate).  Ick.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Not just the enum, but `Query::Column` and the lack of `struct` and `enum` keywords where C requires it. I don't know C++, so I wasn't aware of the flexible array member problem; I assumed it was just mis-tagged by accident.

Answer (score 0):

The correct expression should be more like this:

`size = val->count * (sizeof(Validations) + sizeof(Query) + (sizeof(Query::Column) * q->columnCount));`

But note that you probably have to add up the column counts for each individual Query if they can vary.

Comment: They can vary. Could you give me an example? :)

Comment: @pirox22 I meant at allocation. Don't you need to account for different Query sizes? For example if one Query has 5 Columns and another has 7, then the total required memory would be ``2*sizeof(Val) + 2*sizeof(Query) + (5+7)*sizeof(Col)``

Comment: @pirox22 I edited the answer, because I think I got the expression wrong the first time.